# destroy current tabbarVC after instantiate new VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Very similar to Instagram, the main part of my app has five tabs with five ViewControllers all connected to one tabBar Controller via navigation controllers. When the user tapped Logout button, I want to be able to send the user back to the Login VC that is located before the TabBar VC (As shown in the image) and also "Destroys" anything that is associated to the tabBar controller (1 x tabbar VC, 5x navigation VC, 5x ViewControllers) However, I can not simply do "DismissViewControllerAnimated method" because upon launch, I set the tabBar VC to be the initial VC if the user have previously logged in. This is achieved by the following code in the app delegate

```
func tryToLogin() {

    if let userUid = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(KEY_USER_UID) {
        print("User Exists in NSUserDefault = \(userUid)")
        updateUserGlobalVariables()

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarVC") as! UITabBarController
        window?.rootViewController = tabBarVC
    }
}
```

At the moment, when the user logs out, I "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" to go back to the LoginVC as LoginVC may never appear if the user has already logged in.  However, it seems like when I log back in with another account, some of the data from my variables gets carried back as if the VC/TabBarVC never gets destroyed.Here is how I go to my LoginVC at the moment.

```
func goToLoginVC() {

    let facebookManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    facebookManager.logOut()

    do {
        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
        self.removeCurrentUserDataFromDisk()

        // Dont use dismiss as sometimes the root VC is not login VC
        let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! LoginVC
        self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true) {
            self.removeFromParentViewController()
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        showErrorAlert("Error", message: "\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

So I guess in other words, How do I achieve the same result as dismissViewControllerAnimated by 
1. InstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier 
2. Destroy what was left behind that was attached tabBarVC

Here is a screen shot of my storyboard

[image: Instagram Storyboard]

Thanks

Comment: One option would be to change the `rootViewController` of the window and dismissing the previously visible view after the switch. The "downside" to this is that you'll have to create custom transitions if you want smooth transitions.

Comment: You should be able to use an unwind segue to get back to the login VC from anywhere but to do that you need to use a segue to go from the login VC to the tab bar VC rather than using presentViewController but that is pretty trivial

Answer (score 0):

If your loginVC have embed with navigation controller then you can do something like on logout click,

```
   UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *initialViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];


UINavigationController *nav = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];

[nav setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:initialViewController, nil] animated:NO];



AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];



CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.2;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = nav;

[appDelegate.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil ];
```

I am doing this in one of my project. `navigationController` is the storyboard identifier for `UINavigationController` embed in your first LoginViewController. You have tagged `Objective C` in question that i have write obj c code snippet, If it may help. :)

Comment: My login vc does not have any navigation controller as shown in the attached image. Thanks for the response though

Comment: You can embed it in navigation controller to make flow easier!

Answer (score 0):

To implement such flow i use UITabbar element in some container view controller and add all the child controllers programatically to tabbar. On transition among viewcontrollers on different tab selection you can use transition animation as it works with uitabbarcoontroller. this approach let me embed uinavigationcontroller in loginviewcontroller itself and make that as root always. if user is already logged in then in navigationController's viewcontrollers property add containerview as second element, this will show container on top. and while log out just pop to root viewcontroller. This approach will also help you add or remove tabs and controller in future without touching storyboard. I you like and want some coding example please let me know i would love to post the code also.